# Can't save parsed API data to state in React Native

Tags: react-native

Using React-Native I'm trying to pull from an API, convert the provided XML to JS using react-native-xml2js and save it to state.

I have the converted output pushed to console successfully but when I try to save to state and have that state outputted on screen I'm getting a reference error stating that result is not defined.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { parseString } from 'react-native-xml2js'

class MPList extends Component {
   state = {
      data: '',
   }
   componentDidMount = () => {
      fetch('http://data.parliament.uk/membersdataplatform/services/mnis/members/query/House=Commons%7CIsEligible=true', {
         method: 'GET'
      })
              .then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseText) => {
             parseString(responseText, function (err, result) {
               console.log(result);
               return result;
              })
            this.setState({
              data : result
              })
             })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error fetching the feed: ', error);
          });
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text>
               {this.state.data}
            </Text>
         </View>
      )
   }
}

export default MPList
```

New to this, any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the state from within the `parseString` callback function. I've used an arrow function so you don't need to add explicit bindings.

```
parseString(responseText, (err, result) => {
  if(result) {
    this.setState({ data: result });
  }
});
```

Your current code:

```
parseString(responseText, function(err, result) {
  // result is defined here
});
// result is undefined here
this.setState({ data: result });
```

Comment: That did the trick, I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!